# contact form reloads with notifications

Tags: jquery, contact-form

I have a contact form I'm using, I'm loading it into my website using jquery load, you can see it here when you click contact: www.klossal.com

The problem happens when ever the form tries to notify you about something, whether it's that your e-mail is sent or that you forgot to put in your name.  I'm newer to php and jquery so I'm not exactly sure how to prevent this from happening.  These reloads don't seem to happen when they happen on the original page www.klossal.com/contact.php.  It seems like the page does a complete reload, is there anyway to keep these little notifications on my page?

I load it into my page like so:

```
$("#contact_form").click(function() { $("#content_1").load("contact.php"); });
```

and the code for the contact page is as follows can be looked at by simply going to http://www.klossal.com/contact.php and looking at the source.  It's long which is why I didn't post it here.  Any help I could get on this would be great, it's the last thing I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the console: you have an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier contact.php line 70

You do not escape a quote that is part of the string.

---

You should also use something like

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

Instead of just using `return false;` to stop form submission, although I don't think that's a problem here.

Comment: so you don't think that's what causing the problem I'm talking about though?

Comment: Not the second part of my answer, but I think the first part is.  I divided them with a horizontal rule.

Comment: hmm, I'm not exactly sure where to put that, where would it go in that page?  Sorry, I'm newer at this.

Comment: @loriensleafs where would *what* go on the page?  You have a syntax error that you need to correct.

Comment: sorry, I miss read what you said and was looking at the second part.  I'm not sure what you mean by "You do not escape a quote that is part of the string."

Comment: You have code that says something like `('Message I'd like to help');`.  Notice how there are three single quotes in a row, so there is a syntax error.  Replace `I'd` with `I\'d`.

Comment: thanks so much for being patient with me on that, I really appreciate it!